# OpenLayers 3 textfile layer?

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to migrate from OpenLayers 2 to OpenLayers 3.
In OpenLayers 2 there was a Text Layer:

```
var pois = new OpenLayers.Layer.Text( "Points of Interest",
                { location:"./textfile.txt",
                  projection: map.displayProjection
                });
```

How to make this Layer in OpenLayers 3? Is it possible to use textfile.txt without changes?

Comment: Is there a German version of this site that you could post to?

Comment: Sorry, but this site is not yet public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no equivalent for `OpenLayers.Layer.Text` in OpenLayers 3. But for example you could use GeoJSON instead, see this [example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/vector-layer.html).